# div display flex text alling

Tags: html, css

hello the subject I couldn't do about css is this, how can i draw this in the image?

what I want to do is to copy the image with html and css.
I tried with display flex and but I couldn't
[image]

```css
.channel-left {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.channel-description {
  width: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="channel-left mb-5">
  <div class="channel-description">
    <div class="channel-img">
      <img src="img.jpg" class="img-circle">
    </div>
    <div class="channel-title">
      <p>title</p>
      <p>blabla</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="channel-subs">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-outline-danger rounded"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> Like</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What do you mean about `this`?

Comment: I found it nice, I try to do the same but I couldn't

Comment: sorry i made a wrong correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.description {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.title {
  padding: 10px;
}

.img {
  border-radius: 90%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.subs {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="description">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/50/50" class="img-circle">
    </div>
    <div class="title">
      <p>title</p>
      <p>blabla</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subs">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-outline-danger rounded">Like</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

just give the simple flex css to parent, put all three items in same div and then give margin-left auto to last item to move it to right,

Rest style your typography and colors.

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}
.channel-description {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.channel-subs {margin-left: auto;}
.channel-title {margin-left: 10px;}
```

```html
<div class="channel-left mb-5">
  <div class="channel-left mb-5">
    <div class="channel-description">
      <div class="channel-img">
        <img src="img.jpg" class="img-circle">
      </div>
      <div class="channel-title">
        <p>title</p>
        <p>blabla</p>
      </div>
      <div class="channel-subs">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-outline-danger rounded"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> Like</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
```

Comment: .channel-subs not on the right.
Thank you for your help. but I don't want to show up

Comment: @KaanDemir this is the exact output shown in your image, do you not want to change the HTML , the way I changed it? or is it something else u need?

Comment: Thank you so much. For your help.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work:

```css
.channel-left {
  background: #1f2227;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: white;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.channel-left,
.channel-description {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.channel-img {
  flex-basis: 80px;
}

.channel-title,
.channel-description{
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="channel-left mb-5">
    <div class="channel-description">
      <div class="channel-img">
        <img src="img.jpg" class="img-circle">
      </div>
      <div class="channel-title">
        <p>title</p>
        <p>blabla</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="channel-subs">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-outline-danger rounded"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> Like</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you've already accepted an answer, however I want to post my own:

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.channel-left {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background: #222222;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.channel-description {
    width: auto !important;
    display: inherit;
    flex-basis: 70%;
}

.img-circle {
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  width: 50px;
}

.channel-info {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.btn-outline-danger {
  background: #555555;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  height: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.channel-subs {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

p {
  color: white;
}

.channel-title {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="channel-left mb-5">
  <div class="channel-description">
    <div class="channel-img">
      <img src="https://www.chiquita.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Chiquita_Banana_Class_Extra_Yellow.jpg" class="img-circle">
    </div>
    <div class="channel-info">
      <p class="channel-title">Title</p>
      <p class="channel-desc">blabla</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="channel-subs">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-outline-danger rounded"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> Like</button>
  </div>
</div>
```